# Why do these coroutines not give the expected output?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I am trying to understand coroutines in Kotlin, but I've hit a bit of a roadblock. In the following example I would expect the following to happen:

- Prints 0
- Setup job 1
- Setup job 2
- Prints 3
- Run job 1
- Waits 1.2 seconds
- Prints 1
- Prints 4
- Run job 2
- Waits 1 second
- Prints 2
- Prints 5
- Prints 6

But it prints this:

0
3
2
1
4
5
6

I don't really understand why this is happening. I mostly don't understand how the output of `job2` can come before `4`. I am very confused.

```
println("0")
runBlocking {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch {
        // launch new coroutine and keep a reference to its Job
        delay(1200L)
        println("1")
    }
    val job2 = GlobalScope.launch {
        // launch new coroutine and keep a reference to its Job
        delay(1000L)
        println("2")
    }

    println("3")
    job.join() // wait until child coroutine completes
    println("4")
    job2.join() // wait until child coroutine
    println("5")
}
println("6")
```

Comment: `join` does not *start* the coroutine, it only waits for the completion. `launch` already starts it.

Comment: `launch` launches the co-routines immediately so you print 3, then `job2` finishes first (while you are waiting for `job`)

Comment: You'd get that output if you used `GlobalScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { ... }` which postpones start until `start()`, `await()` or `join()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading from the [documentation of kotlinx.coroutines#launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html):

> By default, the coroutine is immediately scheduled for execution. Other start options can be specified via start parameter. See CoroutineStart for details. An optional start parameter can be set to CoroutineStart.LAZY to start coroutine lazily. In this case, the coroutine Job is created in new state. It can be explicitly started with start function and will be started implicitly on the first invocation of join.

So your coroutine starts immediate after the `launch` command. This should explain the order of executed commands. The `delay` in your async coroutines is executed right away while the main thread executes the next statements. `3` before `2` before `1`. Then you wait until your first job is finished (printing `1`) before printing `4` from the main thread.

If you want your code to be executed like you expect it, you can add the `start = CoroutineStart.LAZY` parameter to the `launch` like this:

```
println("0")
runBlocking {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        // launch new coroutine and keep a reference to its Job
        delay(1200L)
        println("1")
    }
    val job2 = GlobalScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        // launch new coroutine and keep a reference to its Job
        delay(1000L)
        println("2")
    }

    println("3")
    job.join() // wait until child coroutine completes
    println("4")
    job2.join() // wait until child coroutine
    println("5")
}
println("6")
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what happens:

1. **print 0**
2. enter [`runBlocking`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html), which blocks the current thread until the block is finished.
3. setup and [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) [job](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/index.html) 1; The job starts execution immediately and is suspended for 1200ms by the delay statement.
4. setup and launch job2; The job starts execution immediately and is suspended for 1000m by delay statement.
5. **print 3**
6. wait (execution is suspended) until job 1 finished (`job.join()`).
7. after 1000 ms job2 **prints 2** and finishes
8. after 1200 ms job1 **prints 1** and finishes
9. **print 4** (because job 1 has finished)
10. wait (execution is suspended) until job2 finished (`job2.join()`). This returns immediately, as job2 has already finished.
11. **print 5**
12. **print 6**, after the [runBlocking](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html)-block finishes and the thread where it was started continues.

You may read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html to get a better insight into suspending  functions. What helped me understand coroutines was this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hfBv0a09Jc